# How to insert category with my id in nopcommerce ?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I have xml with categories and I need to transfer these Categories(with Ids) to nopCommerce. Xml looks like this:

```
<ROW>
  <C0>4</C0>
  <CODE_GROUP_WARES>546</CODE_GROUP_WARES>
  <CODE_PARENT_GROUP_WARES>141</CODE_PARENT_GROUP_WARES>
  <NAME>MOBILE HDD </NAME>
  <SIGN_ACTIVITY>Y</SIGN_ACTIVITY>
</ROW>
```

Every category has subcategory --> I have to insert exactly my Ids. Id's generated db do not work for me.

I found information that I have to change mappings for category.

```
this.Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

But for this operation I need to use: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Category ON`

I'm working with nopcommerce through API and I do not know how to use `IDENTITY_INSERT` with API. And also I bought user guide and it does not describes how to use `IDENTITY_INSERT` with API.